# How to setparent state form child component by fetching data from API

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-state-management

I have two component parent and child and i want to set parent component's state from child component during render by fetching data from api. I have wrote a code to fetch data from api in child component and while trying to update child parent component state, useEffect hooks in child component ask to pass parent setState as dependencies and when i pass it. It fetch api continuously. Is there any best approach?

Comment: If you only want to set the state on the mount, replace dependency array with `[]`. Passing `setState` will trigger execution on each rerender of parent as well as child.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass `state` and just pass `setState` from parent to child. You need to wrap the child component to `React.memo`